# Where is json.config file found in the root of the project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in development field.

I have already made an app in create-react-app.
But now I have been asked to submit `json.config` file..

It is mentioned that -

> The file must be called config.json and must be stored in the root level of your project.

Here is the format of the configuration file:

```
{
 "install": "npm install",
 "run": "npm start",
 "port": 3000
}
```

I am unable to find it in my project folders and dependency folders and files.

Answer (score 0):

Create-React-App creates this file for you under the hood. So you don't have to setup it. You can open the terminal and write `npm install` and after `npm start`. That will open your web app in `http://localhost:3000`.

More details https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts

Edit: Dependencies should be inside the `package.json` in the root directory.